# Что нужно учесть при создании и подключении домена

Tags: dns

Здравствуйте!

До сих пор пользовался асашайскими хостами $4-7 в месяц + "бесплатный домен в подарок". В первый раз столкнулся с проблемой перевода домена(2 месяца). Тогда и зарегал себе домен независимо от пакета хоста. Теперь, когда решил завести 10 доменов всплыла нужда разобраться в этом вопросе раз и навсегда так сказать заполнить пробелы. Знаю в принципе зачем нужен DNS. Руками, если что, уже делал. При этом всём теряюсь в догадках, что конкретно нужно сделать, если хочу управлять 10 доменами? Сами имена(домены второго уровня) зарегать надо в любом случае, не важно даже где. Главное - прикрутить их к DNS и к IP и, как вариант, смотрю на [DynDNS пакет 6-10 доменов](http://dyn.com/dns/dynect-managed-dns-lite/) в который входит DynECT Managed DNS Lite(рулевая панель доменами) и [Domain Registration](http://dyn.com/dns/domain-registration/)(сама регистрация доменов). Почитал так-же про [Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/?hl=ru) и понял, что он отличается от DynDNS видимо тем что у них домен не купишь, а только вроде как панель рулевая есть. В общем советуйте кто на что горазд!

Любые полезные ссылки статей на данную тему для расширения кругозора приветствуются. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

да много где можно купить. Большинство регистраторов предоставляют услугу днс и панель к ней, где все достаточно просто.

работает это примерно так:
на днс сервере указываете ИП адрес своего сервера и домен/поддомены, на впс уже разруливаете.

я покупал домены .ru/.рф по 99рублей штука (за год столько же), там же предоставляется и панель руления днс сервером, впс дешевый и хороший (судя по тому где они арендуют сервера -- hetzner.de) по 131руб за месяц (за год 1300 получилось), единственно что там траффика только 1.5Тб в месяц. На этом ВПС есть так же панель управления ДНС.

Comment: Много где - само собой. Покупал, указывал, всё работает исправно, а понимания всей картины нет и "пощупать" как будто чего-то не хватает, но уже начинаю понимать постепенно. Вот чтобы увидеть лучше гугловский ДНС или нет, надо прицепить к нему свои домены с хостовской панели ДНС вручную либо через саппорт чтоли?

Comment: по поводу Google Public DNS -- это не то, что вам нужно, это вообще не для этого :) Эт чтобы использовать их днс на вашем компьютере, а не для сайта. Для сайта у них это ЕМНИП корпоративная услуга и не бесплатная.

Comment: >> использовать их днс на вашем компьютере
<br>
всмысле, чтоб повесить домен надомашний сервак? и только?

Comment: нееее, на вашем комьютере прописаны адреса ДНС серверов, где Ваш компьютер будет узнавать ИП адрес сайта, на который вы заходите через браузер и все. никаких никуда не повесить :)

Comment: мм.. надо будет потестить конэкшн :) спасибо!

Comment: Та на здоровье)

Answer (score 1):

думаю это

[image: думаю ЭТО]

Comment: 18 минут 24 секунды. не плохо

Comment: а кто у тебя там в лутших за 2 секунды. в 25 чекбоксах по 5 вариантов набирает? ))))))))))))))) я бы так не смог )))

Comment: какой русский не любит быстрой езды

Comment: ладно будет интернет побыстрее я побью этот рекорд (честным путем)

Comment: попробуй без интернета с листом и ручкой ;)

Comment: да тоже самое и вышло только бы таблицы чертить пришлось. спрашивается зачем ты вообще это в интернет выложил тогда?